# Symfony3 "The option "placeholder" does not exist."

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to create a user settings panel.

In the form I would like to have a placeholder with the current value the user has for his param.

Here is a sample code:

```
//...

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->add('Username', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => "Change UserName",
                'placeholder' => $userData[0]->getUsername()
            ))
//...
```

Using such values I get this error in the browser:

> The option "placeholder" does not exist. Defined options are:
>   "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize",
>   "block_name", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints",
>   "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id",
>   "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data",
>   "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message",
>   "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters",
>   "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "method",
>   "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required",
>   "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message",
>   "validation_groups".

The problem is only with the parameter itself because `'data' => $userData[0]->getUsername()` works and displays the correct information.

Here are the use parameters of my page:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use AppBundle\Entity\Task;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Post;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`placeholder` is an HTML attribute and can be added using the TextType [`attr`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#attr) option.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('Username', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => "Change UserName",
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => $userData[0]->getUsername(),
            )
        ));
```

Comment: The option "type" does not exist.