# Symfony render required on TextField true

Tags: symfony

I don't understand why the rendering of this subform doesn't render the `required` tag on my TextType `firstName`;

My form in based on a `Order` entity
`OrderFormType` has a CollectionType of `Tent`, based on `TentFormType`
`TentFormType` has a CollectionType of `Camper`, based on `CamperFormType`

So Order > Tent > Camper

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
//...

class CamperFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
            'required' => true, //Should even not been usefull since SF2.8
            'label'    => 'First name',
            'attr'     => [
                'placeholder' => 'First name'
            ],
        ]);

        //...
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class'      => 'AppBundle\Entity\Camper',
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            'error_bubbling'  => true,
            'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
            //...
        ]);
    }
}
```

The fields are simply rendered with a form_widget:

```
{{ form_widget(form.firstName) }}
{{ form_widget(form.lastName) }}
```

But that not add the `required` field:

```
<input id="app_order_form_type_tents_0_campers_0_firstName" name="app_order_form_type[tents][0][campers][0][firstName]" placeholder="First name" class="form-control" type="text">
<input id="app_order_form_type_tents_0_campers_0_lastName" name="app_order_form_type[tents][0][campers][0][lastName]" placeholder="Last name" class="form-control" type="text">
```

I could do

```
{{ form_widget(form.firstName, {'attr': {'required': 'required'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.lastName, {'attr': {'required': 'required'}}) }}
```

But it shouldn't be required with my FormType...

Does anyone knows why ?

**--EDIT--**

My `Camper` Entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Camper.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="camper")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Camper
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstName", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $firstName;

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Can you just paste your entity here?

Comment: Just did it :) !

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, i can not use comments so i put a suggestion here...
Try:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: I already have `form_start` and `form_end`

`form_widget(form)` will render all my fields in the same place, that's not what I wanted.

Comment: Placeholder needs to be in attr?

Comment: Yes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200549/symfony3-the-option-placeholder-does-not-exist

Comment: Since you have @Assert\NotBlank() in your entity, maybe you can leave required out.

Comment: Indeed, but the user can submit the form without fill it
And that's not user-friendly

Required is a HTML5 validation.
Assert\NotBlank is a back-end validation

I'd like to get both.
The problem is not realy how to get the required field, I can have it with `{{ form_widget(form.firstName, {'attr': {'required': 'required'}}) }}`, the question is "Why did it not render by default while it should?"

Comment: Yeah, i agree, i just want you to get something that works and go from there.